# Проблема с <ScrollView>

Tags: android, xml

При создания любого ScrollView в привю ошибка, только в моем проекте

```
    org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: unterminated entity ref (position:TEXT �PNG


IHDR...@32:8 in java.io.InputStreamReader@6ce6bc3) 
    at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.exception(Unknown Source)
    at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.pushEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.pushText(Unknown Source)
    at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.nextImpl(Unknown Source)
    at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeXmlBlockParser.next(BridgeXmlBlockParser.java:301)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.ResourceHelper.getInternalComplexColor(ResourceHelper.java:176)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.ResourceHelper.getColorStateList(ResourceHelper.java:237)
    at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getColor(BridgeTypedArray.java:293)
    at android.widget.EdgeEffect.<init>(EdgeEffect.java:122)
    at android.widget.ScrollView.setOverScrollMode(ScrollView.java:1669)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3985)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4102)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:578)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:97)
    at android.widget.ScrollView.<init>(ScrollView.java:180)
    at android.widget.ScrollView.<init>(ScrollView.java:176)
    at android.widget.ScrollView.<init>(ScrollView.java:172)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor366.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.onCreateView(BridgeInflater.java:107)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:717)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:785)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:149)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:230)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:426)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:520)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:508)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:967)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:508)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.access$600(RenderTask.java:75)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:620)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:617)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.runRenderAction(RenderService.java:371)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:617)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:639)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.doRender(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:654)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.access$1700(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:82)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7$1.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:596)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:142)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:446)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:392)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:127)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:591)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:337)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:327)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$3.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:271)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:286)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:244)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:234)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:352)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Пример скрола

```
    <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView" />
```

Где копать помогите (